# HP UFT Statement to Exit Component but not group?

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

we have several Test components grouped. I'd like to do some parameter validation at the beginning and skip the component altogether when certain conditions are met. I wanted to use *ExitComponent* for this, however I figured this does not only leave the component but the whole group.

I really do not want to use extensive if-else statement ranging over my whole component, which is the only solution I can see now.

Example:

```
'Skip component if value is empty
if Parameter("Par1) = "" Then

    'Cannot use ExitComponent as I do not want to leave the whole component group
    ?????

endif

'Start processing data in the component
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The approach from BPT is to use the ALM Wizards and Forms in order to create and configure almost all Aspects of your Tests. If you select a flow or a Test Case you can configure the [Run Condition](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/online_help/Content/BPT/c_testplan_conditionoverview.htm) of each Subcomponent / flow in the Test Script Tab. As the Linked documentation tells, you can do it based on Parameters.

[Here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/online_help/Content/BPT/t_testplan_setrunconds.htm) is the tutorial for setting Run Conditions.

**P.S**: In case you have to check complex things and not simple parameters, well:
Create a component that checks the complex stuff (the relation of stellar objects regarding the sun - just kidding, of course some AUT specific condition) and shares the info with the world via an **Output Parameter**. The subsequent components can of course then react to the ***Parameter***.